# Unable to decode QR code using any Python libraries but works on QR scanners app

Tags: python, opencv, qr-code, zxing, zbar

Following is a QR code captured from holography experiment with highest level of error correction. I can decode the image using my native camera app on iPhone but unable to decode using any of the Python QR code decoding libraries.

[image]

```
#---- Using opencv ----#
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
val, pts, qr_code = detector.detectAndDecode(img)
print(val)

#---- Using zxing ----#
import zxing
reader = zxing.BarCodeReader()
result = reader.decode('image.jpg')
result_content = result.raw if result else "Unable to decode"
print(result_content)

#---- using zbarlight ----#
from PIL import Image
import zbarlight
image = Image.open('image.jpg')
image = image.convert('L')

codes = zbarlight.scan_codes(['qrcode'], image)
decoded_code = codes[0].decode('utf-8') if codes else "Unable to decode"
print(decoded_code)
```

I understand that the image has noise and pincushion distortion in it. I just don't understand how a simple iPhone camera app can decode it straight away but none of the above libraries couldn't.

Comment: welcome back. I remember your optical experiments from last time. you can't decode this because it's blurry. there is radial blur. the code is also severely distorted in non-linear ways. that breaks many of the assumptions of QR detection and decoding.

Comment: Thank you @ChristophRackwitz Does this mean all smartphone cameras remove radial blue before decoding? Could you recommend anything I could do before/after/during the image capture to avoid this issue?

Comment: Or is there a way i could mimic the camera operation using a python library and then try to decode the image?

Comment: no, smartphone cameras may simply have good optics, or bad ones. blur cannot be removed by filtering (do *not* investigate Wiener deconvolution, you will never be able to estimate the per-pixel PSF in this situation). this requires good optics first. avoid the issue occurring in the first place. do not try to fix up bad results.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I hear your point 